# Forecasting Bimonthly data

Tags: python, time-series, forecasting

I have a bimontly data for 2 years for sales and the data looks like this

```
Date_time_index Customer exposure.
 1/3/2015. 234.
 15/3/2015. 560.
 1/4/2016. 789.
 15/4/2016. 678.
 1/5/2017 222.
 15/5/2017. 456.
```

So basically I want to predict the bimontly sales for the 2018 data.

Since python does not accept the date time index for the regression and if I convert the dates into the number of days, the data would looks like this

```
Days. Customer_exposure.
 15. 23.
 14. 560.
 15. 789.
 14. 678.
 15. 222.



ce_lm3 = smf.ols(customer_exposure~ days', data=differenced_series).fit()
```

The above conversion of the bimontly data into days does not seem very correct and wise to me , can anyone's suggest me how can I convert this time series index into days so that I can predict the exposure for customer for 2018.

Note,,: I can't convert my dates time index to the month number since this is a bimonthly data and not monthly or at any other level.this strictly needs to be bimonthly.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `datetime` object in the `datetime` module has a useful function `strptime()` which allows one convert a string to a `datetime` object using the `format` parameter:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> a = datetime.strptime('1/3/2015', '%d/%m/%Y')
>>> b = datetime.strptime('15/3/2015', '%d/%m/%Y')
>>> print (b-a).days
14
```